# gfortran 4.9.0 bug? WHERE statement optimized away

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have a section of code that's producing different results under gfortran between a debug build and an optimized build.

```
PROGRAM test

IMPLICIT NONE

REAL, DIMENSION(10) :: a = 0.0
REAL, DIMENSION(10) :: b = 1.0

WRITE (*,*) b
WHERE (a .ne. 0.0) b = a
WRITE (*,*) b

END PROGRAM
```

When I compile this as a debug build, it produces the correct result. When I compile it as an optimized build, it replacing every element of b with a.

```
$ gfortran test.f
$ ./a.out
1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
$ gfortran -O3 test.f
$ ./a.out
1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0     
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

If this is a compiler bug, how can I work around it?

Comment: Tests for equality on reals can give unexpected results. Don't do it unless you understand the issues.

Comment: There is no gfortran 4.9.0. The current trunk doesn't exhibit this problem on Linux x86-64.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your problem. I'm using

gcc version 4.9.0 20140313 (experimental) (GCC)

on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (Ubuntu 12.04 amd64). For me, your example program results in:

`$ gfortran where.f
$ ./a.out 
   1.00000000       1.00000000       1.00000000       1.00000000       1.00000000       1.00000000       1.00000000       1.00000000       1.00000000       1.00000000

   1.00000000       1.00000000       1.00000000       1.00000000       1.00000000       1.00000000       1.00000000       1.00000000       1.00000000       1.00000000

$ gfortran -O3 where.f 
$ ./a.out 
   1.00000000       1.00000000       1.00000000       1.00000000       1.00000000       1.00000000       1.00000000       1.00000000       1.00000000       1.00000000

   1.00000000       1.00000000       1.00000000       1.00000000       1.00000000       1.00000000       1.00000000       1.00000000       1.00000000       1.00000000`

So, which version of gfortran are you using? Remember that 4.9 is not yet released, so the date of your prerelease version may be significant. Furthermore, which target (that is, OS & bitness) are you using? If you built GCC yourself, did you run the GCC testsuite to check that your gfortran build works otherwise and is not hopelessly broken?

Comment: `Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gfortran
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/4.9.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Configured with: ../gcc-4.9-20130929/configure --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.0 20130929 (experimental) (GCC) ` I just wanted to be sure that this was purely a bug in the compiler and not exposing wrong with my code.

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing wrong with your code and the Intel Fortran compiler produces the same, correct, output with and without the `-O3` flag.  While, as @eriktous points out, there are delicacies to be observed when comparing floating-point numbers, both `0` and `1` are precisely representable (certainly on any machine which implements IEEE floating-point arithmetic) and comparisons for equality such as your code exhibits should be fine.

If this is a compiler bug, and I suspect that it might be, the usual workaround would be to use another compiler (version).